# Docusign Rest API - Update User using PUT method - can we change userStatus

Tags: docusignapi

I am exploring update user and I want to update users status using PUT method but userStatus is not getting updated?

Is that not allowed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you're able to provide a code example (Using fake data) of the API call you are attempting we can get a better look at what might be causing this PUT call to not work.

These are the following options a user can have for their userStatus:

ActivationRequired
ActivationSent
Active
Closed
Disabled

These values are unable to be changed via the API. Is there a specific user case you need for this to be achieved via the API?

You can, however, close a user membership via a DELETE call to the following URL:

/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users